# Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.cleanup()" because "this.nameEnvironment" is null

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-8, compilation

Getting error: Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on the project. Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.cleanup()" because "this.nameEnvironment" is null

[Eclipse showing error while building project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJB0S.png)

below is the error :

> Errors occurred during the build.
> Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project.
> Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.NameEnvironment.cleanup()" because "this.nameEnvironment" is null

I am using the latest version of eclipse which is :

```
Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0)
Build id: 20220908-1902
```

Comment: What version of Eclipse? Is there a more detailed message in the .log file in the workspace .metadata?

Comment: According to your screenshot, you are using a pretty old Eclipse. Please upgrade.

Comment: okay, I'll try after upgrade

Comment: This is the latest version : I am still facing the same issue.

Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0)
Build id: 20220908-1902